# How to fix ERROR TypeError: "_co.loadedRecipe is undefined", ERROR Error: "[object Object]"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, angular8

I'm learning ionic/angular and am trying to use the routing thing where information is passed through the path like so

```
path: ':recipeId',
```

because I have a list of items with id's so I'd like to be able to click on the item and be taken to a detail page for that list item.

I successfully display the page with the list of items (lets say its at /recipes) but when I click an item going to the detail page (/recipes/id) I error out with:

> ERROR TypeError: "_co.loadedRecipe is undefined"
>       View_RecipeDetailPage_0 RecipeDetailPage.html:11
>       Angular 24
>       RxJS 5
>       Angular 11 RecipeDetailPage.html:11:4
>       View_RecipeDetailPage_0 RecipeDetailPage.html:11
>       Angular 16
>       RxJS 5
>       Angular 11

This points at the module's (or component's? new to angular) `html` code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title> {{ loadedRecipe.title }} </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-img [src]="loadedRecipe.imageUrl"></ion-img>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <h1> {{ loadedRecipe.title }}</h1>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-item *ngFor="let ig of loadedRecipe.ingredients">
                        {{ ig }}
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

and it looks like loadedRecipe is **undefined** here.

> Here's the controller ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RecipesService } from '../recipes.service';

import { Recipe } from '../recipe.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-detail',
  templateUrl: './recipe-detail.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-detail.page.scss'],
})
export class RecipeDetailPage implements OnInit {

  loadedRecipe: Recipe;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private recipesService: RecipesService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.paramMap);
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
        if (!paramMap.has('recipeId')) {
            // redirect because we don't have id that we need
            return;
        }

        console.log(paramMap);
        const recipeId = paramMap.get('recipeId');
        this.loadedRecipe = this.recipesService.getRecipe(recipeId);
    });
  }

}
```

> app-routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'recipes', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'recipes',
    children: [
    {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: './recipes/recipes.module#RecipesPageModule'
    },
    {
      path: ':recipeId',
      loadChildren: './recipes/recipe-detail/recipe-detail.module#RecipeDetailPageModule'
    }
    ],
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

> list controller recipes.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RecipesService } from './recipes.service';
import { Recipe } from './recipe.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipes',
  templateUrl: './recipes.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipes.page.scss'],
})
export class RecipesPage implements OnInit {

  recipes: Recipe[];


  constructor(private recipesService: RecipesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recipes = this.recipesService.getAllRecipes();
  }

}
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with the activated route but I'm just kinda at a loss. New to debugging on the web too so any pointers would be great.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for the same?

Comment: ++ I think you'll need to fetch the *recipeId* using : `const recipeId = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('recipeId');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicholas K has you headed in the right direction. I figured an example would help out too.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

 const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'recipes', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'recipes', loadChildren: './recipes/recipes.module#RecipesPageModule' },
   { path: 'recipe-detail/:id', loadChildren: './recipe-detail/recipe-detail.module#RecipeDetailPageModule' },
 ];

 @NgModule({
   imports: [
     RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
   ],
   exports: [RouterModule]
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In recipe-detail.page.ts as Nicholas K mentioned you can access the params in the activated route like this

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
   if (this.id != null) {
     console.log('id: ' + this.id);
   }
 }
```

And you can navigate from the recipe page to the detail page like this (you could also use routerLink instead of the click event to navigate)

**recipes.page.html**

```
 <ion-content>
   <ion-list>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" (click)="routeToRecipeDetail(recipe.id)">
       {{recipe.name}}
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

**recipes.page.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-recipes',
   templateUrl: './recipes.page.html',
   styleUrls: ['./recipes.page.scss'],
 })
 export class RecipesPage implements OnInit {

   recipes = [
     { id: 1, name: 'pizza' },
     { id: 2, name: 'hamburgers' },
     { id: 3, name: 'salad' }
   ]

   constructor(private router: Router) { }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

   routeToRecipeDetail(id: number) {
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/recipe-detail/' + id);
   }

 }
```

I created a github repo [here](https://github.com/RichTillis/ionic-routing-example) if you want to take a look.
Hope this helps